# "Call to undefined function finfo_open()" bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I'm tried to deploy my app on bluemix and got "Call to undefined function finfo_open()"

which way is correct to include fileinfo.so in modules list on bluemix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the PHP module `fileinfo` to the `options.json` file.

If you don't have the `options.json` file yet, you can create it under the `.bp-config` directory in your application root directory.

The `options.json` file should have the following format:

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "fileinfo" ]
}
```

After creating this file push your application again using cf push.